# ¿Cómo configuro una pantalla redimensionable en pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Quiero hacer una pantalla redimensionable en pygame pero los cambios en esta no se adaptan al tamaño completo, por lo que el espacio añadido a la ventana se queda vacío.

Lo que quiero es que al 'pintar' la pantalla se pinte completa...

Pongo un ejemplo del código que representa como lo tengo:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), pygame.RESIZABLE)
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    screen.fill ((155,155,155))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2):

Citando las respuestas de ninMonkey y Edward en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603222/allowing-resizing-window-pygame):

Lo que está pasando es que no estás actualizando tu alto y tu ancho cada vez que la pantalla está siendo redimensionada.

Según la documentación de [pygame.display](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html):

> If the display is set with the pygame.RESIZABLE flag, pygame.VIDEORESIZE events will be sent when the user adjusts the window dimensions.

Del evento [pygame.VIDEORESIZE](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) puedes obtener el `size`, `w`, `h`.

**Ejemplo de código:**

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

# Crea la ventana
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((350, 250), pygame.RESIZABLE)

pygame.display.set_caption("Prueba de Redimensionado")

while True:
    surface.fill((255,255,255))

    # Dibuja un rectángulo rojo que redimensione la ventana como prueba.
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (200,0,0), (surface.get_width()/3,
                                          surface.get_height()/3,
                                          surface.get_width()/3,
                                          surface.get_height()/3))

    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        # Este es el código que redimensiona la ventana
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            # Recrea la ventana con el nuevo tamaño
            surface = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h),
                                              pygame.RESIZABLE)
```